# Run program until completion without debugging step by step

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

I am debugging a program but I no longer want to run step by step. Is there no "resume program" function that I can use to let the program I'm attached to, to run to completion of all its tasks without the debugger pausing every second (no breakpoints enabled). Maybe the access violations are why it's pausing but I want it to ignore them too as it's already excluded in my exceptions menu.

Comment: @Sigtran I am reverse engineering a program that has an expensive process at the end of its function, I am trying to skip through this bit sometimes and debug it some other times. No, I can't simply open the program manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both, ollydbg and x64dbg you can just press the "run" button(or F9) to let the programm run normally. You may have to disable the breakpoints beforehand(This will not delete them). In x64dbg you do a right click in the breakpoints panel and select "disable all" in the context menu to achieve this.

To "ignore" all exceptions in x64dbg: Click on options -> preferences -> exceptions -> add range. Then in the first input enter a "0" and in the second as many "F" as fit in.

Comment: You're right. I think it was a bug that it wasn't registering the disabled breakpoints. Thanks